# URL rewrite all php files in subfolder to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup a way to rewrite all php files in a subfolder to index.php

What I have been trying until now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /simple

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php
```

It does not work 100%, now it takes the CSS, IMG and all other files too, which it should not, only the PHP files.

- When I go to http://localhost/simple/  it loads correct.
- But when i go to http://localhost/simple/test/ all the CSS and images does not load, cause the directory doesn't exsist.

Hope some can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /simple/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Or this rule:

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: It does work allmost, except that it cannot load .css files or images.

Comment: Is it possible to send all to index.php except preconfigured files as .css, .png, jpg etc

Comment: For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: I just made af google search and found this: RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L] - How can I implement that?

Comment: That's not needed actually since I already have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. You have use `<base...>` tag as I wrote above.

Comment: It works thanks! . But is it possible to do with: RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L] - And how?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ index.php` is the way

Comment: is it possible to send all to index.php except .css, .png, jpg etc.